# Type for a curryfied function that create a new instance

Tags: typescript, error-handling, currying

So, i have the next function in ts:

```
export function createErrorInstance(error: unknown): Error {
    return new Error(getErrorMessage(error));
}
```

But now i want to create a curried function, that will accept the constructor `new Error` or `new ServiceError` so later on will return an other function expecting only for the error.

```
export const errorBuilder  = (builder: new (arg0: string) => any) =>
    (error: unknown) => 
        new builder(getErrorMessage(error))
```

which could be used as:

```
export const createErrorService = errorBuilder(ServiceError)
```

and later on, simply like: `createErrorService(error)` if i am in a try/catch fetch or `createValidationError(error)` if i am in a try/catch form validation.

Now I want to set it up the correct types, cuz now the signature for my `createErrorService` function is:

`const createErrorService: (error: unknown) => any`

but i wanted it to be:
`const createErrorService: (error: unknown) => ServiceError`

Maybe i need to update the signature for `errorBuilder`, but i dont know how :(

Comment: "but when I try: `export const createErrorService: ServiceError`" why would you try that? Shouldn't it be `(error: unknown) => ServiceError`?  Ideally all code in a question would form a [mre] that demonstrates the problems you're having and doesn't have unrelated problems.  Since `getErrorMessage()` and `ServiceError` have not been declared, anyone wanting to test an answer they give you has to declare these for themselves, and brings up the possibility that these declarations differ in a meaningful way from the ones you imagine them having.

Comment: because `errorBuilder(ServiceError)` is a currified function. (maybe that is what i am doing wrong) 
`getErrorMessage` get the error and return a message string. 
`ServiceError` extends from `Error` class nothing special.

Comment: I don't think you understood me.  You wrote `const createErrorService: ServiceError = errorBuilder(ServiceError)`, but that doesn't make any sense, and of course the compiler would complain.  That problem is almost completely unrelated to the issue you were having; even in my fixed version below, writing that would give you the same warning because you're claiming that `createErrorService` is a `ServiceError` instead of a function that returns `ServiceError`s.  Like claiming that a toaster is a piece of toast, or that a printer is a document. I've removed that bit, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `errorBuilder()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the subtype of `Error` that the `builder` parameter constructs.  Like this:

```
export const errorBuilder = <T extends Error>(builder: new (arg0: string) => T) =>
  (error: unknown) =>
    new builder(getErrorMessage(error));

// const errorBuilder: <T extends Error>(
//   builder: new (arg0: string) => T
// ) => (error: unknown) => T
```

The generic type parameter `T` represents the subtype of `Error` that you care about.  Note that it is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Error` via the `T extends Error` declaration, so you can be sure that `T` must be assignable to `Error`.  The type of `errorBuilder` as shown above is therefore a function that takes a constructor of type `T` and returns a function whose return type is `T`.

Let's test it out:

```
export const createErrorService = errorBuilder(ServiceError);
// const createErrorService: (error: unknown) => ServiceError

const err = createErrorService({ a: 123 });
// const err: ServiceError
```

Looks good.  The type of `createErrorService` is `(error: unknown) => ServiceError` as desired, and therefore any error you create with it is a `ServiceError`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMBRGGHGAWRAGdaoiAKEcgLnjQGtUcB3VAEoOtDDCyoCAbngB6WYWR1aAWABQ6kAA8ADpQxI0mXPjBwoGEGQowAkqlFR0IFuUoduvAcPjXK8AG91eHg4DGQYfFQQPl83GCYiUniaekYXVhtBQSl1AF91TV19eDA8UXhMygAhZCwIUBh4AF54AB4AFUqtS1RgWjibAD4mACM6htYOaNimWAIABhExCQJBFqH4DvXmoeD4VxsPVB5+IQ39kJn4cfrGxOI-amV0w8ps3I01eVLygyqYLU7lN2l1tL1+oNKCN1D8QrdJjBpjEDvMlvBROJJDtNh1YQocQcAcdTt4NltCmpIFB6PAAMqsABuWDAVni3QhAyegTkCgISno+ygLXgAEZPgUvto9DADGUHHLzJYngyYMzWSKAUDEUxVeq2VlPj95RUzCALAbKHqWSAOG8kZwTl5zrt6UybU9KSb-uQRWaLSr3aymAF4FAOKKAEwAZngeRy+N+Csq7Ddao98SAA)